# How to query SP logging database for most clicked items and how long

Tags: 2013, database, site-usage

I am currently playing around with the SharePoint logging database (by default [WSS_UsageApplication]). What I want to know are two things:

- how I can query for most visited list items
- how can I query for how long a user visited a page

There is no documentation on the database model on this to be able to do a self-study :(

Comment: If i were i would query IIS Logs.

You can copy all IIS Logs from all SharePoint front end then use the LogParser. You can see the example below:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/02/06/how-to-analyse-iis-logs-using-logparser-logparser-studio/

Comment: here is some queries example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries/